# Factory panic alarm going off after changing battery [97 Toyota Camry]

Tags: toyota, battery, camry, alarm

We just changed the battery in our 1997 Toyota Camry now as soon as we connect the battery the panic alarm goes off and all the doors lock. How do we stop this / turn it off.

///note: the battery in our remote is dead///

Comment: This isn't an answer but a compliment to suggestions above. My sister and fiance were sitting in a supermarket parking lot for quite some time b/c car alarm locked the engine. The alarm went off accidentally. Since remote alarm battery died, couldn't start car. After reading this, I recommended turning the key in the ignition at least 5 times....it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously the easy fix is replace the battery in your FOB then just hit unlock once you hook up the battery. But...

If you are too lazy to replace your FOB battery. Try just putting the key in the ignition in the "ON" position then hooking up the battery.

If that doesn't work then try cycling the key between off and on (not start) 5 times.

If that doesn't work then make sure all doors are closed and unlocked before disconnecting and closed and unlocked before reconnecting.

If that doesn't work pull the fuse for the horn and go find a fob battery.

Comment: laziness has nothing to do with we don't have a replacement battery and our car.. ya well you know that part, cycling the key did the trick but surprisingly not the ignition but in the door. it locked us out of the car so we had to wait for the extra set keys for it

Comment: Nice answer. Could you explain why these things would work?

Answer (score 3):

If the alarm is a "factory" alarm, cycle the key in the ignition from off to on (where the dash indicators light up), 5 times. This is the reset procedure for the "factory" alarm. Otherwise look in the owners manual where there is a red button under the steering wheel, possibly behind a panel. These process is performed when doing maintenance. Either way, you want to make sure to re-engage it when you get it working or you will not have the alarm.

Answer (score 3):

Same thing just happened to my 93 landcruiser...changed battery and alarm kept going off, it shuts off after a few cycles but the immobilizer would not allow the car to start. Tried everything, and while all cars are different here’s what worked for me: disconnect the negative terminal, put the key to the ‘on’ position, leave the drivers door open, reconnect the negative terminal, turn the key to the start position and it should fire up and reset the alarm. This is the only suggestion that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If your Alarm is going On after replacing Your battery.

## 1 there is a code you need to enter into the FACTORY radio.

The radio is part of the alarm system.
You must Pull the radio and Call Acura dealer/ Acura themselves. There is an 8 digit code that will give them the 5 digit code you will need to enter. (write it down on owners manual for future ref.)
turn Key to "ON" (not start)  position.
Hold the #1 and #6 buttons simultaneously and turn on radio.
It will ask for the 5 digit code . You will see "CODE" on screen enter it now.
This should turn off your alarm and reset the car.
If for some reason it does not repeat process. In my case it still would not reset the car even though the radio is now in FM radio display mode-functioning.
I quickly disconnected and reconnected the NEG BATT terminal and it reset the car.
Hope it helps anyone w/ this prob who still owns a 97 Acura.

Comment: I'm wondering how calling Acura for the code going to help them out with their Toyota?

Comment: lmao           
i guess acura are just that nice...

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem. Try disconnecting both terminals and touching them together a couple of times. (Once you reconnect them, the alarm should go off for a couple of seconds and then turn off) While you are doing this. Your car key should be in ignition and in the start position with the door opened. Hopefully this worked and your car was able to start.